# What's the difference between Github and Nuget?

Tags: github, nuget

What's the difference between Github and Nuget? I don't quite understand either of them.

Answer (score 8):

GitHub is a web-based hosting service for software development projects that use the Git revision control system. GitHub offers both commercial plans and free accounts for open source projects. According to the Git User's Survey in 2009, GitHub is the most popular Git hosting site.

NuGet is a Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to install and update third-party libraries and tools in Visual Studio.